# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. "Render Login"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I have this issue, and I can not figure out what I'm missing?
In error it tells me to check Login render.
This is the Login render:

```
<Box>
      {login ? (
        <Profile email={email} loggedOut={callBack} />
      ) : signUp ? (
        <SignUp cb={signUpSuccess} />
      ) : (
        [
          <Box>
            <Title>Employee entry</Title>
            <Pbox>
              <Labal>Email</Labal>
              <InputCap
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Your email address here..."
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Pbox>
            <Pbox>
              <Labal>Password</Labal>
              <InputCap
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Your password here...."
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Pbox>
            <Btn onClick={loginUser}>Login</Btn>
            <br />
            {signUp ? <SignUp /> : <Btn onClick={signUpUser}>SignUp</Btn>}
          </Box>
        ]
      )}
    </Box>
```

i work with react hook and styled component!
thanks!

Comment: There is no need to render it as an `array`. Remove the brackets `[]` or add a prop `key`  to `Box`. Like this `<Box key='foo'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an array when for grouping a single component `<Box>...</Box>`:

```
<Box>
  {login ? (
    <Profile email={email} loggedOut={callBack} />
  ) : signUp ? (
    <SignUp cb={signUpSuccess} />
  ) : (
    <Box>...</Box>
  )}
</Box>
```

But if you still going to render inside an array, you should assign a `key` prop for each component rendered, in this case only for `Box` component:

```
<Box>
  {login ? (
    <Profile email={email} loggedOut={callBack} />
  ) : signUp ? (
    <SignUp cb={signUpSuccess} />
  ) : (
    [<Box key="someKey">...</Box>]
  )}
</Box>
```

As a side note, when you want to group components (instead of using an array `[<Comp1/>,<Comp2/>,...]` you should use [`React.Framgent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a issue with using the squre brackets around the 
it recognized as an array, did you try to add the key property and the error will gone? or try not to use those square brackets [] around the box.